# Finding a range of appropriate values for P.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

For the question,

A variable number $p$ is such that $3 - 2p \leq 6 + p \leq 3(14 - p)$. I have to find the set of possible values of $p$, writing my answers in the form $m \leq p \leq n$, where $m$ and $n$ are integers.

I tried solving this through trial and this seems excessively long and hopeful that there might be a more clever alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$3-2p\leq6+p\leq42-3p$$
Solving separately 
$$3-2p\leq 6+p$$
gives
$$-3\leq3p$$
$$-1\leq p$$
For other
$$6+p\leq 42-3p$$$$4p\leq36$$
gives
$$p\leq9$$
combining gives 
$$-1\leq p \leq 9$$
id est $p \in[-1,9]$